# MySQL - Update same record that I am SELECTing

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm in the process of writing a web crawler. All links are stored in a MySQL database. Because I will be running the crawler on multiple nodes, I need to set URLs as 'being crawled' as fast as possible to keep things efficient.

My web crawler is written in C#. Right now, it downloads the URL and ID, then it sets the URL as crawled with the ID. The problem is that is takes 2 different queries. Is there any way to combine them together?

Here is my current code:

```
string stm = "SELECT * FROM pages WHERE IsCrawled = 0 LIMIT 1;";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, conn);
cmd.ExecuteScalar();
id = -1;
using (rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (rdr.Read())
    {
        URL = rdr.GetString(1);
        id = rdr.GetInt32(0);
    }
}
MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE pages SET IsCrawled = 1 WHERE ID = '"+id+"'", conn);
update.ExecuteScalar();
```

Again, I'd like to combine the queries together.

Comment: `Convert.ToString` returns `string`. If you want to use it's return value, you should assing it a _string reference_ by the way.

Comment: i think if you were using an orm (linq, ado.net, etc.) you could do what you are asking about. using this approach, i think you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

To do the update and select all in one, you can do this, however, i'm not sure you can make this work in the context of your program flow.

```
UPDATE pages SET IsCrawled = 1 WHERE ID IN
(SELECT ID FROM pages WHERE IsCrawled = 0 LIMIT 1;)
```

Comment: Would changing ID to * break it? I assume so, but it's not very important to me if I can't get the other fields.